# How to make Carousel Materialize Change Height Between Mobile and Desktop

Tags: css, slider, materialize

The Carrousel Materialize does not change height keeping in default 400px.

I would like that according to the device that accesses the site the slide had its height the proportional value changed.

Example computer with default height of 400px and mobile 200px.

Site.css configuration

```
.slider .slides li img {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[image: Problems css resize]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Comment: Do you have the solution to the problem?
Thank you for translating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you'll remove that css part of yours then it'll be fine.

[image]